# Understanding the behavior of .call and .apply in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, this

I read from the MDN docs that the first argument of .apply and .call is the "this" object, but

```
var stringToEval = "console.log(this)";
eval.call(null, stringToEval);
eval.apply(null, [stringToEval]);
```

in the code above both lines end up logging the Window object (in a browser). Shouldn't it log null, that is what I passed as the first argument in both methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters):

> The value of this provided for the call to fun.  Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

The global object is window.

**Edit** since it doesn't matter whether you pass in null, undefined, or an object with eval. Inside `eval`, `this` will be the same as `this` right before the eval call.

As per section 15.1.2.1 of ECMA-262 5.1, eval takes in a string and parses it as ECMAscript. If it is valid ECMAscript then it runs it, in the context that it was called from. So in your case you can think of the calls to eval as if they replace themselves with `console.log(this)` at runtime. With that replacement you end up with the program:

```
var stringToEval = "console.log(this)";
console.log(this);
console.log(this);
```

Which makes it clear why it outputs the `DOMWindow` object twice. You can get around it like this:

```
var stringToEval = "console.log(this)";
(function(str){ eval(str); }).call({not: "empty"}, stringToEval);
(function(str){ eval(str); }).apply({not: "empty"}, [stringToEval]);
```

Since when eval replaces itself with `console.log(this)` it will be in the context of that anonymous function in which `this` will refer to the object passed in.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/u3VGh/)

Comment: Well, var stringToEval = "console.log(this)"; eval.call({}, stringToEval); eval.call("", stringToEval); eval.call({not : "empty"}, stringToEval); still all return the Window object... It's not null or undefined anymore...

Comment: That's an indirect eval call, `this` will always be `window`. It has nothing to do with `.call` or `.apply`

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo No problem :) It was definitely an interesting question :)

Answer (score 0):

You call `eval` with explicitly set `this` to `null`, this has nothing to do with what the `this` object will be inside the evaled
code, nowhere is it said that `eval` evaluates the code with `this` set to the same `this` that you called `eval` with. In fact, doing so is calling `eval` [indirectly](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) and results in the eval code being run in global context for modern browsers.

Therefore, you want to test with normal function:

```
function test() {
    console.log(this);
}

test.call({});
test.apply({});
```